# JSON renders into HTML with only last <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Please read the question **at the end of this post**, thanks.
I can't seem to find why the JSON is rendering only the last **li** element from the JSON. I'm new and green and I need 'elp!

**HTML:**
Just an `<a href="#" id="clickme">Get JSON</a>`

**This is the JSON Object Array**

```
{"id":"1","mesi":"mesima 0","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"2","mesi":"mesima 1","done_bool":"0"},{"id":"3","mesi":"mesima 2 ","done_bool":"1"},{"id":"4","mesi":"mesima 3","done_bool":"1"}
```

**Ajax Script:**

> ```
> $(function(){
>
>     $('#clickme').click(function (){
>         //fetch json file
>
>
> $.ajax({
>     url:'data.json',
>     dataType: 'json',
>     success: function(data){
>
>         var items = '';
>         $.each(data, function (key, val) {
>             items += '<li id=" ' + key + '">' + val + '</li>';
>         });
>         ul = $('<ul/>').html(items);
>         $('body').append(ul);
>
>     },
>     statusCode: {
>         404: function(){
>             alert('there was a problem with the server. try again in a few secs');
>         }
>     }
>
>     });
>
>     });
> });
> ```

At the end I am expecting to receive a list of these items where "done_bool" would be a radio checkbox and every li is basically a task and it's either "done" (1) or "not done" (0).

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. So jQuery will fail to parse it as JSON, not run the success handler, and run the error handler (which you don't have) instead. You need to provide the code that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: log `data` and see whether the object parsed from the json meets your expextations

Comment: some guy here called Maddy edited my Ajax and screwed it up, I guess by accident, check out his edit, if you can please fix that, I dont think I have enough rep for that.

Comment: The original JSON was invalid though, and still is.

Comment: Hi Quentin, thanks. I am new and I don't know where the code is problematic, I just know I am getting an erroneous output/render. You can see the result here: http://prntscr.com/9pxk9u

Comment: so no one can find why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I already posted this answer but it got deleted/erased.. I dont know why.. but I hope it helps you..

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){

                var html = "<ul>";
                items = data.map(function(obj){
                   html += "<li id='" + obj.id + "'>" + obj.mesi + "</li";
                });
                html += "</ul>";

                $('body').append(html);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in you JSON.Also i have changed the logic a bit to generate UL and LI

```
    var data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "mesi": "mesima 0",
    "done_bool": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "mesi": "mesima 1",
    "done_bool": "0"
  }, {
    "id": "3",
    "mesi": "mesima 2 ",
    "done_bool": "1"
  }, {
    "id": "4",
    "mesi": "mesima 3",
    "done_bool": "1"
  }];
  var items;
  $('body').html("<ul></ul>");
for(dat in data){
$("ul").append('<li id='+data[dat]["id"]+'>'+data[dat]["mesi"]+'</li>')

}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/tqszL97d/)

Comment: Hi Nofi, thanks for answering, but why did you change the logic a bit? I am getting this info from a JSON encode on another PHP file. Also, please take note that the json encode doesn't place var data = [{   ...   }]